# How to create a copy of tinymce editor control dynamically while drag and drop from one div to another div ? in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

i want to create a newsletter templates in asp.net and for that i need to drag and drop the tinymce editor to create a newsletter template and drag the control from one div and drop the control into another div or placeholder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Could you specify in more detail what you want to do? + add some code you tried already.

Comment: i have include the jquery fucntion for drag and drop now i stuck up with creating a tinymce or any html editor dynamically in the form i had refered the link http://jqueryui.com/droppable/shoppingcart and modify the functionality for drag and drop now i want to create a editor at the end of drop event